# pyramid: load a file of json and send part of the json object

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pyramid, wsgi

I would like to load a JSON object from mongo query, access part of the object and then have this serialised and sent to the web client.  I can get the web client to work not the python side.  Any examples would be great..

The request is a serialised JSON object like this

```
{"page":"home"}
```

the mongo query results would be like this, but each "home", "hello" etc has many more keys and values in them.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a8838782430d5ae7526e9eb"), "home" : { "next_page" : "/stats"}, "hello" : { "next_page" : "/home" }, "stats" : { "next_page" : "/hello" } }
```

The views.py code includes this, which I provide as pseudocode.

```
@view_config(route_name='nav_route', renderer='json')
    def content(request):
        page_name=request.page              #that is, I want page_name="home"
        mongo_json=mongo_query(woof)        #load and parse the above query
        page_nav=mongo_json[page_name]      #get the part for "home"
        return {'nav': page_nav}
```

UPDATE: With feedback this now works - cheers!

```
@view_config(route_name='rachel_content', renderer='json')
def rachel_content(request):
    page=request.json_body['page']
    result=db.rachel.find_one()
    return { 'rachel' : json.dumps(result[page])}
```

(Rachel is named after the replicant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you simply need to dump the JSON data.  I tend to default to using the [simplejson](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package so would add this to the top of the file.

```
import simplejson as json
```

Then simply tell it to dump your dictionary object to a JSON string by using the `dumps` function:

```
return {'nav': json.dumps(page_nav)}
```

I believe you can do the same with the [built-in JSON library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) if you don't want/can't install simplejson

Comment: What's the purpose of json.dumps() in this case, considering that the output will be converted to json anyway? JSON inside JSON is more like Inception, and @Craig was

Comment: ... and @Craig was more going with Blade Runner theme :)

Comment: @Sergey you are completely correct.  I missed the fact that code was already using a JSON renderer on the output.  I guess if it works then the calling element is expecting it to be double encoded.